# Transfering data from WF to its host process (thread)

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I don't know WF very well. I am just trying to know how to transfer some information from running Workflow to its Hosting Application. I don't want to say about transfer data at the end of workflow process. My workflow is long-running. But from time to time it must send some info objects to the host application. Could anybody tell me what is a name of such technology or give me any references to msdn or some other resources. thanks.

PS. This workflow will work asynchronously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways you can go about this but the most common way is to use a custom activity with a workflow instance extension, sometimes called activity extension.

See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patcarna/archive/2010/01/19/windows-workflow-4-0-workflow-instance-extensions.aspx) for more info.